# FirewallD: add service without specifying a zone

Tags: firewall, firewalld

I was wondering which zone would service be added if run the add service command without specifying a zone.

For example:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will be added to the default zone 
        firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
will give you default zone